# How Can I View / Edit Build Command Of An AWS CodePipeline / CodeBuild Project?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm using CodePipeline, and I have many stages in my pipeline. I have a build stage that uses a buildspec.yml file. However, I also have a stage with Action Category "Test", and this stage is meant to only run tests (and to do it *before* the build stage). When creating this action I can choose "Create a new build project" and then enter in information about the OS and runtime I want it to use.

I can also enter a "Build command". Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about:

[image]

However, after I save and go back in to edit the action the input box disappears! Instead, it just has the bullet for "Select an existing build project" selected. I can click "View project details" and then "Edit project", but for some strange reason I not only can't edit the build command but the build command is not even displayed anywhere in the project details at all! I would think this is the most important piece of information in the build project so the fact that it is not displayed is completely baffling to me.

Is this just a bad UI on AWS's part, or am I missing something here? How do I view / edit the build commands?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully, it turns out that you can view (and edit!) the build command.

Just click "View project details" and "Edit project". Then scroll down to a spot where it says, "Current build specification".

If you click on "View build specification" you can see the build command, and if you click "Update build specification" then you can modify it.

Yay!